# Counting points in polygon by time in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, point-in-polygon, date, count

I want to count the points in the polygon by time category.

[image]

However, the point have time category.
[image]

When I want to use `Vector > Analysis Tools > Count points in polygon` option, it does not consider the time category. It counts all the points and does not give separate by time.

[image]

Shortly, how could I count the points in a polygon by date/time?

Comment: There is a question here which asked a similar question a couple of years ago, although the accepted answer seems to produce some interesting results: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338357/calculating-number-of-points-within-polygon-which-are-filtered-according-to-a-gi

Comment: Placing an "or" in the title makes this two questions. Please ask only one question per Question.

Comment: I dont understand. You want to count unique acq_dates?

Comment: I want to estimate what is the number of points in a given location on a given date. For instance, Layer of X has 10 points in 01/08/2018 and 5 points 02/08/2018 and so on.

Comment: I have removed R from the question title to prevent it from beeing closed as not focused. Feel free to rollback my edit if you prefer. For an R solution you can try https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420955/counting-points-in-polygon-by-time-attribute-condition.

Comment: Also note that your date is not a date, its a string. So you can only do a single attribute join condition but not count them for a date range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because I think this is a very interesting question and a good use case, I wrote this little processing tool. Copy paste the code to a `.py` file and place it in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts` (respectively Linux/Mac paths). You can then find in your processing toolbox within `scripts -> from gisse -> Count Points in Polygon by Datetime`.

A modified version of this script is now also part of the [ProcessX-PlugIn](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProcessX/) you can get in the official QGIS Plug-In repository. You can find it in your processing toolbox in `ProcessX -> Vector - Creation -> Create Timepolygon with Pointcount`. Alternatively you may also want to try *Count Features in Features with Condition* or *Count Points in Polygons With Condition* algorithms.

It requires:

- A field of type DateTime in your Pointslayer
- A given start- and end datetime you can enter as string
- A given interval in seconds

It does:

- Count the Points in Polygons by the given datetime of the points
- Creates a new polygon-copy for each datetime-range and adds the pointcount, fromdatetime and todateime as attributes
- If Point- and Polygonlayer are not in the same CRS, the Pointlayer is temporarily reprojected to the polygonlayers crs (no output is generated for that one)

The script:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsField, QgsFeature, QgsProcessing, QgsExpression, QgsGeometry, QgsPoint, QgsFields,
                       QgsWkbTypes,
                       QgsFeatureSink, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsSpatialIndex,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink, QgsProcessingParameterDateTime, QgsProcessingParameterField,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource, QgsProcessingParameterEnum, QgsProcessingParameterString,
                       QgsProcessingParameterNumber)
import processing
from datetime import *
from math import ceil


class CountPointsInPolygonByTime(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    POLYGON_LYR = 'POLYGON_LYR'
    POINT_LYR = 'POINT_LYR'
    DATETIME_FIELD = 'DATETIME_FIELD'
    START_DATETIME = 'START_DATETIME'
    END_DATETIME = 'END_DATETIME'
    INTERVALSEC = 'INTERVALSEC'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.POLYGON_LYR, self.tr('Polygon'), [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], 'polygons'))
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.POINT_LYR, self.tr('Point'), [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], 'points'))
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.DATETIME_FIELD, self.tr('Datetime Field'), 'datetime', 'POINT_LYR'))
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                self.START_DATETIME, self.tr('Start Datetime in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format'), '2020-01-01 00:00:00'))
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                self.END_DATETIME, self.tr('End Datetime in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format'), '2020-01-10 23:59:59'))
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
                self.INTERVALSEC, self.tr('Interval in Seconds'), 0,
                86400))  # Indicator as number. 0=Int, 1 would be double; 1=default number
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT, self.tr('TimePolygons with Pointcount')))  # Output

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        lyr_polygons = self.parameterAsLayer(parameters, self.POLYGON_LYR, context)
        lyr_points = self.parameterAsLayer(parameters, self.POINT_LYR, context)
        fld_time = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.DATETIME_FIELD, context)
        start_date_string = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.START_DATETIME, context)
        end_date_string = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.END_DATETIME, context)
        intervalsec = self.parameterAsInt(parameters, self.INTERVALSEC, context)

        if lyr_polygons.sourceCrs() != lyr_points.sourceCrs():
            reproj = processing.run("native:reprojectlayer",
                                        {'INPUT': lyr_points,
                                         'TARGET_CRS': lyr_polygons.sourceCrs(),
                                         'OUTPUT': 'memory:Reprojected'})
            lyr_points = reproj['OUTPUT']

        fields = lyr_polygons.fields()
        fields.append(QgsField('from_datetime', QVariant.DateTime))
        fields.append(QgsField('to_datetime', QVariant.DateTime))
        fields.append(QgsField('pointcount', QVariant.Int, len=0))

        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context,
                                               fields, lyr_polygons.wkbType(),
                                               lyr_polygons.sourceCrs())

        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        total_seconds = int((end_date - start_date).total_seconds())
        idx_points = QgsSpatialIndex(lyr_points.getFeatures())

        required_iterations = ceil(total_seconds / intervalsec)
        total = 100.0 / (lyr_polygons.featureCount() * required_iterations) if lyr_polygons.featureCount() else 0
        current = 0

        for current_interval in range(0, total_seconds, intervalsec):
            current_start_datetime = start_date + timedelta(seconds=current_interval)
            current_end_datetime = (
                        start_date + timedelta(seconds=current_interval + intervalsec) - timedelta(seconds=1))
            for polygon in lyr_polygons.getFeatures():
                current += 1
                new_feat = QgsFeature(fields)
                new_feat.setGeometry(polygon.geometry())
                idx = 0
                for attr in polygon.attributes():
                    new_feat[idx] = attr
                    idx += 1
                new_feat['from_datetime'] = current_start_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                new_feat['to_datetime'] = current_end_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                new_feat['pointcount'] = 0
                for pointid in idx_points.intersects(polygon.geometry().boundingBox()):
                    point = lyr_points.getFeature(pointid)
                    if feedback.isCanceled():
                        break
                    if point[fld_time] >= current_start_datetime and point[fld_time] <= current_end_datetime:
                        if point.geometry().intersects(polygon.geometry()):
                            new_feat['pointcount'] += 1
                            idx_points.deleteFeature(
                                point)  # dont count a point twice, removing it from the index speeds up the code around 25%

                if feedback.isCanceled():
                    break

                sink.addFeature(new_feat, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)
                feedback.setProgress(int(current * total))

        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}  # Return result of algorithm

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return CountPointsInPolygonByTime()

    def name(self):
        return 'CountPointsInPolygonByTime'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Count Points in Polygon by Datetime')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('FROM GISSE')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'from_gisse'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr('This Algorithm counts points in polygons by a given datetime condition')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very nice solution to the problem. The code creates a layer named "TimePolygons with Pointcount" and it contains a field named "pointcount". However, all the values are zero, probably I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @AlperD. did you convert your date-string to a datetime field first? The tool only works with datetimes, not strings.

Comment: Thank you @MrXsquared. That was the problem. I should have converted the string to a date field.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Join attributes by location` with your `Points` as `Base layer` and `Polygons` as `Join Layer`

Then use `Statistics By Category` with `Joined Layer` as the `Input Vector Layer`

`id` as `Field to Calculate Statistics On`

For the `Fields with categories` parameter use `id_2` (which is the `id` field from the `polygons`) **and** `date`

[image]
[image]

The output will be a table that has a `count` for each polyon `id` and each `date` (plus several other statistics fields which you can ignore or delete). This table can be joined back to your polygon layer using `id_2` and a selected `date`. Otherwise, you could pivot this table and join the whole pivot table back.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Matt. Your answer solves my problem. One more thing before applying your method, I had to create an id variable in the points file by "Open field calculator" in the "Open Attribute Table" with the expression of "@row_number". After creating the id variable, I applied your method and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Using QGIS expressions

create a new field in the polygon layer, and populate it with this expression:

```
array_to_string(
    with_variable('arraydate',
        aggregate(
        layer:='Point', 
        aggregate:='array_agg', 
        expression:="date",
        order_by:="date",
        filter:= intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent))),
array_foreach(
      array_distinct(@arraydate),
             @element||': '||array_count(@arraydate,@element))
))
```

[image]

Comment: It gives the following error: "Eval Error: Cannot find layer with name or ID 'Point', even I try the names in my polygon file.

Comment: you have to write the name of the layer with points

Answer (score 1):

Although it creates new data files, which may not be desirable, I would:

1. Use the Split Vector Layer tool to split the point file into multiple layers each with points with a unique date
2. Run Count Points in Polygon for each unique date layer

You'll end up with a polygon file with multiple fields, each representing the point count for that specific date.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Considering more than 300 regions and 1000 days of time, splitting into multiple layers would not be very feasible.

Comment: I can see not! It probably needs a programmatic approach in that case.